# How to Serialize class derived from ReadOnlyCollection

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, datacontractserializer, readonly-collection

When I try to serialize my own class that is derived from ReadOnlyCollection I get the error:

*Type 'MyReadOnlyCollection`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' with CollectionDataContractAttribute attribute is an invalid collection type since it does not have a default constructor.*

Now the error makes sense, it's true I do not have a default constructor. However I am able to Serialize a ReadOnlyCollection using the DataContractSerializer even though ReadOnlyCollection does not have a parameterless default constructor.

```
// OK
ReadOnlyCollection<string> readOnlyCollection = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" });
string result1 = Serialize(readOnlyCollection);

// Throws InvalidDataContractException
MyReadOnlyCollection<string> myReadOnlyCollection = new MyReadOnlyCollection<string>(new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" });
string result2 = Serialize(myReadOnlyCollection);

public static string Serialize(object o)
{
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(o.GetType());
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder))
    {
        serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, o);
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}

[CollectionDataContract]
public class MyReadOnlyCollection<T> : ReadOnlyCollection<T>
{
    public MyReadOnlyCollection(IList<T> list) : base(list)
    {
    }
}
```

Two questions:

1. Why can I serialization ReadOnlyCollection but not my derived class?
2. How should I serialize my derived class correctly?

**Update:**
I've added my derived class above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*`How should I serialize my derived class correctly?`*
to serialize your derived class  correctly  you should do something like this

```
[DataContract]
public class MyReadOnlyCollection<T>:ReadOnlyCollection<T>
{

    public MyReadOnlyCollection(IList<T> list) : base(list)
    {
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You cannot use `[CollectionDataContract]` because it does not fully meet collection type requirements as the **Add** method is missing so the type is not considered as a collection type

For more information  [**`Collection Types in Data Contracts`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I have update my original post with my class. However I am using [CollectionDataContract], is this correct?